# Multiplying two sets of data (x,y values, but different x density) followed by integration of the product

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, dataset

I've been trying to do this by myself today, but no luck yet. Please, see attached image.

[image]

Basically, I do have two data sets `A (x1,y1)` and `B` (x2,y2). Please, note that `x1` and `x2` have different range and density. Say `x1` goes like 200, 201, 202... but `x2` goes like 180, 180.5,181,181.5..

There is two tasks I would like to write a code using Mathematica:

1. Find the product of multiplying of two different set (`c`).
2. Calculate the integration of the product and compared to that of the original (x1,y1) (`A`).

Because these two data sets have different range and density, I was thinking about using `Interpolation[]`, but I feel like there should be a simpler way to do this job done.

The 1st data set looks like this:

```
{{Baseline 100%T,},{Wavelength (nm),%T},{2500,27.0365},{2499,27.1329},{2498,27.0761},{2497,27.2015},{2496,27.2032}, ...2289... ,{206,58.9478},{205,59.2311},{204,59.4642},{203,59.7953},{202,59.6811},{201,59.7263},{200,60.0759}}
```

The 2nd data set looks like this:

```
{{Wave length,Spectral irradiance},{280,2.54*10^-26},
{280.5,1.09*10^-24}, ...1698... ,{2490,0.0035},{2500,0.00703}}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "multiplying of two different sets"? Could you give a simple example of the operation  you have in mind?